# STL: Accessing data from a structure that has been added as the second pair to a map

Tags: c++, stl

I have a map like this:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Copied_Instrument_Data> InternalIdWise_Copied_Instrument_Data;
```

where, `Copied_Instrument_Data` is a struct:

```
typedef struct 
{
    std::string type;
    std::string marketListId;
    std::string sectorCode;
    std::string validToDate;
    int notificationType;
    bool npgFlag;
}Copied_Instrument_Data;
```

I inserted data into my map using:

```
InternalIdwise_Copied_Instrument_Data__Map.insert( std::pair<std::string, Copied_Instrument_Data >(internalId, CID) );
```

Where CID is a `Copied_Instrument_Data` structure variable.

Later I used : `iter = InternalIdwise_Copied_Instrument_Data__Map.find("SomeKeyString");`

after  declared `iter` like this: `InternalIdWise_Copied_Instrument_Data::iterator iter;`

Then I have :

```
if (iter != InternalIdwise_Copied_Instrument_Data__Map.end() )
        Instrument_available = true;
if (Instrument_available == true)
{
        ins_todate = *(iter).second.validToDate;
       std::cout<<ins_todate; 
}
```

How ever, this does not work. I am not getting any data in `ins_todate`.

So, my question is :

How to correctly access that element ?

Comment: You do know that in C++ you don't need `typedef struct ...`? The actual structure identifier acts as a type.

Comment: You actully do an `if(condition) flag=true; if (flag) {...do stuff...}` You might have just moved this block instead of the flag assingment you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with operator precedence:

```
ins_todate = *(iter).second.validToDate;
```

uses the dereferencing operator on `iter.second.validToDate` (the dereference (`*`) operator has lower precedence than the element selection (`.`) operator).

You should do

```
ins_todate = (*iter).second.validToDate;
```

or

```
ins_todate = iter->second.validToDate;
```

Comment: What does `operator*` do on a `std::string`? I can't find it as a member: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: Ok, great, but can you please look at the earlier code as well. Do you think I am doing other things right (apart from what you already mentioned in teh comment:)). Please take a look. Thanks

Comment: @MarkRansom Well, that kind of the point isn't it? The OP tries to dereference the string while he/she should dereference the iterator.

Comment: My point is that if it's being interpreted as you say, and there's no `operator*` for a string, it should result in a compile error instead of incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but some suggestion to coding style here:

I.
If you're writing C++, you should do:

```
struct Copied_Instrument_Data
{
    ...
};
```

instead of

```
typedef struct 
{
    ...
} Copied_Instrument_Data;
```

The latter gives an un-named `struct` and then you `typedef` it, which is unnecessary, and you can't use forward-declaration on this `struct`.

II. 
You can use `std::make_pair` to insert element into map, I personally think it's clearer and easier:

```
Map.insert( std::make_pair(internalId, CID) );
```

III.
Temporary variable should be replaced if it's only a flag, i.e.

```
if (iter != InternalIdwise_Copied_Instrument_Data__Map.end() )
        Instrument_available = true;
if (Instrument_available == true)
{
    ...
}
```

should be

```
if (iter != InternalIdwise_Copied_Instrument_Data__Map.end())
{
    ...
}
```

or, this may be done by a return call to exclude false conditions:

```
if (iter == InternalIdwise_Copied_Instrument_Data__Map.end())
{
    // print some error log?
    return;
}

// continue your work!
```

(You can reference to *Refactoring: Impriving the design of existing code, 2nd Ed., Item 6.3 Inline Temp*)

Hope that helps! :)